# Item within a table Lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk

So I have a table using Lua and within it is a variable, but I can't figure out how to reach it because of its name. I was able to use `json.prettify( _id )` in order to view whats in the table. All I want is the `id` within this table but because of how it's named I can't seem to get what's inside of `_id`, I tried both

`_id[1]` but that == nil
`_id.$oid` but that gave me a runtime error

printed response: `_id = {   "$oid":"597015b757203b04d6941d45" }`

interesting note is that `#_id == 0`

Comment: Try `local _, value = next(_id)`

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
tableName[ 'variableName' ]
```

or

```
tableName.variableName
```

Note: Sometimes you can not use both form for example:

```
tableName[ 'name with spaces' ] -- ok

tableNames.name with spaces -- error
```

I think operator `#` can not be used with non-indexed tables.

Comment: The `#` operator only counts items in the "array" component of the table, but can still be used with any table. That means that `#({5, 3, ["Item"] = true})` will return 2, not 3, as Lua only counts the array part of the table.

Comment: Thank you again! The first option worked, the '$' symbol is what was causing the runtime error when I tried _id.$oid

Answer (score 2):

You need decode json string to Lua table and get value in any way:

```
local   json = require("json")

local  str = [[ { "$oid":"597015b757203b04d6941d45" } ]]

local t_res= json.decode(str)

-- access
print( t_res["$oid"] )
-- or 
local k,v = next(t_res)
print( v )
-- or
for k, v in pairs(t_res) do
  print(v)
  break 
end
```

PS: Lua operator # only for a regular array, with non-nil values.

Answer (score 0):

In order to overcome the fact that the name of the variable included the '$' symbol the correct way to get the variable within the table was to use:

_id['$oid'], this worked.

_id.$oid gave a runtime error.